# DNS protocol,messages

Tags: dns, udp, application-layer

In the DNS message format, in addition to the header fields, there are 4 sections:

-questions
-answer
-authority
-additional info.

The DNS Server, who or what populates the sections: authority and additional info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The authority section** tells us what DNS servers can provide an authoritative answer to our query.
- **The additional section** typically includes the IP addresses of the DNS servers listed in the authority section.